# Adding a second if in a all(... with a for loop in it)

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement

I would like to add an if after the getal in the for loop.

```
if all(number % getal != 0 for getal in primes):
                primes.append(number)
```

I tried this, that did not work. Is if possible to add an if to the getal in the for loop?

```
if all(number % getal != 0 for getal if getal <= sqr_number in primes):
                primes.append(number)
```

Somehow the solutions that you guys give with replacing the if to the end of the code, does not work the same as the current code.

```
def prime(n):
primes = [2,3,5,7]
number = 9

while number < n:
    print(number)
    sqr_number = int(number**0.5)
    if number % sqr_number != 0:
        #print(sqr_number)
        for getal in primes:
            if getal <= sqr_number:
                #print(getal)
                if all(number % getal != 0 for getal in primes):
                    primes.append(number)
    number += 2    


print(primes)
print(sum(primes))
```

Comment: `for getal in primes if getal <= sqr_number` is the proper syntax. But I think it's not very effective because if primes are sorted, once condition is met, the rest of the iterations are useless.

Comment: I only want it to go through the prime numbers till it reaches prime**0.5

Comment: of course. so you need to pre-compute your stop condition, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [syntax for filters in comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-comp_for) is like this:

```
(expr for target in iterable if condition)
```

So you have the `if` in the wrong location, it needs to be at the end:

```
all(number % getal != 0 for getal in primes if getal <= sqr_number)
```

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
if all(number % getal != 0 for getal if getal <= sqr_number in primes):
        primes.append(number)
```

the "filter" condition should be after the loop:

```
if all(number % getal for getal in primes if getal <= sqr_number ):
     primes.append(number)
```

(note: `!= 0` is redundant here)

That said, it's not very effective because once `sqr_number` is reached (if the list is sorted) last iterations aren't used (classic loop could use a `break`)

You could use `bisect` to compute the max useful index of the `primes` table:

```
max_useful_index = bisect.bisect(primes,sqr_number)
```

then this internal loop stops when the number is higher than `sqr_number` (added a protection to avoid possible out of range error, unsure of the need of the `+1`, maybe it needs some finetuning with indexes...):

```
if all(number % primes[i] != 0 for i in range(min(max_useful_index+1,len(primes)) ):
```

Another possibility (maybe simpler to comprehend) is to use `itertools.takewhile` so iteration is exhausted when the limit is reached:

```
if all(number % getal for getal in itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x <= sqr_numberprimes, primes)):
```

Comment: Bisect is in specific library from python? I just started coding with python and still getting used to it. Right now I'm trying to code with just the normal codes.

Comment: `bisect` is delivered with python. It uses dichotomic search to be super fast. You can do something similar with a simple loop, not as efficient, though.

Comment: _"That said, it's not very effective because once sqr_number is reached (if the list is sorted) last iterations aren't used (classic loop could use a break)"_ 
I thought that was why I added the 'all' statement?

Comment: the `all` statement will continue because the comparing filter will skip the test. It will run empty from sqr_number to the end. Had you created a loop, you would have used `break` to break the loop.

Comment: there's a solution with `all` using `itertools.takewhile` that will do what you want

Comment: Can't I use a break with the `all` statement?

Comment: no you cannot. And the code you posted creates 2 loops: an explicit one and one within the `all` statement. Strange.